# Bypassing the Hibernate cache in a transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a strange use case of Hibernate where in a call farther up a large stack needs an unmodified copy of an object that is part of a hibernate transaction.  however, every time I ask Hibernate for a copy of the object, it's returning the version that's already been modified / is part of the transaction.

Is there a way for me to force Hibernate to return the db copy / uncached version of object in question?

Answer (score 4):

Open a new `Session` and get the copy of the object from the new `Session`.

Comment: in case the session opening/closing is delegated to a framework (like spring), then opening a new session might be cumbersome. And generally, opening and closing a session for this issue is a bit like killing a fly with a bazooka :)

Comment: Sessions are supposed to be lightweight. If you want a fresh object, open a session and get it. The session factories are heavyweight, and should always be available via some framework API in case there is a need for it (such as this need).

Answer (score 4):

```
Session#refresh(Object object);
```

> Re-read the state of the given instance from the underlying database.

or you can call `session.evict(obj)` (removes it from the session cache) and `load()` it afresh.

Note that if you are using `EntityManager` instead of `Session`, you won't have the `evict()` method. You can obtain the `Session` this way:

```
Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about hibernate caching, use a stateless session to execute your query. Google Hibernate stateless session to get the details.